# I can't access serial ports even though I'm a member of tty and dialout groups

Tags: permissions, tty

Using Ubuntu Server 19.10 on Raspberry Pi 4. I'm a member of both the DIALOUT and TTY groups (I verified this with id) but I can't access serial ports without using SUDO. I tried changing the permissions on /dev/ttyUSB[0-3] and then I could access the ports but at the next reboot, the permissions were reset and I had to use SUDO again. How can I keep the permissions settings?

Comment: Does `id` show a group matching `ls -l / dev/ttyUSB*`? `grep $USER /etc/group`. Abandon messing with `/dev` permissions & ownerships. Craziness will ensue.

Comment: ls shows 

crw--w---- 1 root tty 188, 0 Feb 2 14:47 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw--w---- 1 root tty 188, 0 Feb 2 14:47 /dev/ttyUSB1
crw--w---- 1 root tty 188, 0 Feb 2 14:47 /dev/ttyUSB2
crw--w---- 1 root tty 188, 0 Feb 2 14:47 /dev/ttyUSB3

and id shows I am in the tty group.